# Multiple instances of same app in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, bundle-identifier

I want to keep three instances of a same app in my iPhone for three different environments: qa, uat, and prod.

As per my knowledge, it can be achieved if I change the bundle identifier of each app.

But if that is the case, I would have to create three different Provisioning Profiles and App Ids since I cannot use wild card (because the app involves APNS).

Is there any other means to achieve installation of the same app in the same iPhone without creating multiple App Ids and profiles?

What will be the best practice for this?

Note: It is a Cordova app which I am building for iOS (though it should not matter but still keeping informed) and the distribution certificate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is the only practice, which is what you describe. Different versions of the app must have different bundle IDs. If they get push notifications, that means different provisioning profiles, but that's a one time step which isn't difficult these days.

Answer (score 2):

You will simply need to use three different bundle-identifiers. This can be set in the `info.plist: CFBundleIdentifier`. You may want to setup different target or schemes that use different versions of the `info.plist`.

Comment: How can we decide which info.plist file will be used ?